# trouble with json response from php in jQuery.ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using $.ajax to get a JSON response from a php script. if i log the data variable from the $.ajax success function it outputs a properly formatted JSON object, however when I try to access properties of the data var it's undefined. here is the php the is being sent back:

```
echo json_encode(array("status"=>true, "success"=>"Login Success", "message"=>"You have been logged in successfully."));
```

and here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            login: true,
            username: $('#login-username').val(),
            password: $('#login-password').val()
        },
        async: false,
        url: "./php/client-login.php",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.status);
            if (data.status) {
                console.log(data.success);
                displayModal(data.success, data.message, "./js/login-modal-code.js");
            } else if (!data.status) {

                displayModal(data.error, data.message, "./js/login-modal-code.js");
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, responseText) {
            console.log(status);
        }
});
```

if i add the `dataType: "json"` option to the $.ajax call I get a parse error and if i try to do `$.parseJSON(data);` to access the data in the data var I get and unexpected token error. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, I've used this setup before and it always has worked before but for some reason it isn't now. anyone see where i've gone wrong?

EDIT: forgot to mention here is the response from the php script:

`{"status":true,"success":"Login Success","message":"You have been logged in successfully."}`

EDIT 2: Here is a screen of my console. the top .length call is the json that was logged from `console.log(data)` and the bottom one is from the response in chrome dev tools network tab for the response from the php script. they line up perfectly yet the second is showing a length of 93, how can i fix this? [image: Console Image]

Comment: At a guess I'd say your PHP script is including something unexpected in the output, like a blank line.

Comment: Whitespace shouldn't cause a problem with parsing JSON, but I suspect some other character is slipping through and you're not seeing it.

Comment: Maybe there's a BOM in the PHP file.

Comment: Put `console.log(data.length)` in the callback (without `dataType: 'json'`). If it's not 91, there's an unseen character in the response.

Comment: okay i rewrote the entire php script (not a long one thankfully) thinking there was some invisible characters somewhere messing up the output, as i've had that case before, and tried as you suggested and the length is 93

Comment: i tried using trim and rtrim on the json before i echo it back and i'm still getting 93 chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a workaround for this problem, first I did JSON.stringify on the data followed by JSON.parse and lastly $.parseJSON() to get a javascript object to work with. Not sure why there are 2 invisible characters being added between when it leaves the php script and reaches the $.ajax call so if anyone knows why let me know

Answer (score 0):

I was reading on [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and found that "dataType: jsonp" does not work with sync request, and you're making this kind of request since you have `async: false`. Turning it on may solve your problem.

Also, give a look at the docs.

Good luck!

Comment: He's using JSON, not JSONP.